# CSS Positioning Issue on Chrome

Tags: css, css-position

In the given site below, I have a sidebar menu with CSS positioning `fixed`. However, when I scroll, the menu seems to lag behind. This behavior seems to repeat itself with the image below it.

I've tested the site on IE and everything's working as expected. I have a feeling it's the embedded object behind the menu causing the problem - But CSS `fixed` positioning should work regardless no? Looking for suggestions or fixes to this issue.

I'm using Chrome 39.0.2171.65, on Windows 7 Ultimate N x64

**[Image of behavior](http://imgur.com/UHDS4P6)**

[**SITE LOCATION**](http://orph3us.com)

Comment: osx chrome 38.0.2125.122 works as expected with no lagging

Comment: I will post image of this behavior

Comment: do you experience the same issue in firefox, safari, opera? (im assuming you're on windows given IE testing)

Comment: it works fine in chrome 38 or safari 7.1 with OS X.

Comment: @haxxxton Persistent issue on Chrome 39, tried on three machines. Will open issue on chromium if no solutions later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was with your object, but exact problem - with css rule "z-index: -1"

I made following changes in developer tool

1) Put your object after all site content

2) Add to your object css left: 0 and **z-index: 0**

3) Add to block .left and .wrapper styles - position: relative and z-index: 1

And after this changes - it looks fine in my Chrome. Hope it helps

Comment: I can't apply 2) as I need it to be behind `.left`. Applying everything together places all the `.left` elements at the back of the viewport - they are the posts on the page.

Comment: If you will add to .left the following styles - position: relative; and **z-index: 1 or heigher** - your content block will stay over your object

Comment: Actually you can just delete **z-index: -1** from your object styles, and it should help to stop block jumping

Comment: Ok, now it looks better. Also i think you should add to your object **top: 0** and it will works good

Comment: Works, thanks! Yeah I added `top:0` to the object cuz of the random gap.